# What species of Cerapoda lived during the Jurassic?

Tags: palaeontology

So far, I've found eleven species of Cerapoda that lived during the Jurassic period. Are there any other known species that I've missed?

The eleven that I've found out about are:

- Agilisaurus
- Albalophosaurus
- Camptosaurus
- Chaoyangsaurus
- Dryosaurus
- Heterodontosaurus
- Othnielosaurus
- Uteodon
- Xuanhuaceratops
- Yandusaurus
- Yinlong

I am a game board designer working on a game related to dinosaurs. The "only" research i did is Wikipedia + the DK book "Prehistoric" + Dino Directory web site + several more lesser sites. I would appreciate any information on other species if my list isn't exhaustive, or literature suggestions that might help me.

Comment: I made your list look better, please look over the edit to ensure I didn't mess up your species names, because I couldn't understand your original list.

Comment: VTC because this looks like a homework question without evidence of any research. If it in fact is not, please provide evidence otherwise.

Comment: I am a game board designer working on a game related to dinosaurs. The "only" research i did is Wikipedia + the DK book "Prehistoric" + Dino Directory web site + several more lesser sites. If finding already 11 Jurassic Cerapoda seems "no evidence of any reasearch" I am sorry, I found it quite hard even to find these eleven names as Cerapoda had their "explosion" in the late Cretaceous. I was hoping to find some more help in finding another example of an early Cerapod. Thank you

Comment: @JohannesWentu I added the info from you comment to the question. Please clarify further if you have more information.

Comment: I can't understand why this question is being voted on for being closed... And how is this a homework question? Please be more diligent when voting to close.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. You ask specifically about Cerapoda, but your list includes several non-cerapod genera (Heterodontosaurus and Agilisaurus). Do you want only Cerapoda, or Ornithischia more broadly?

Comment: @kmm. I am only looking for Cerapoda and unfortunately, from my extremely little experience in this world, i already saw that not everyone agrees with classifications. For instance Agilisaurus is not a Cerapod in WP and is a Cerapod in NHM: http://www.nhm.ac.uk/nature-online/life/dinosaurs-other-extinct-creatures/dino-directory/agilisaurus.html . Same thing with Heterodontosaurus: http://www.nhm.ac.uk/nature-online/life/dinosaurs-other-extinct-creatures/dino-directory/heterodontosaurus.html  How a layman like me should choose who is correct?

Comment: Try starting here, http://www.gavinrymill.com/dinosaurs/Cladogram/CladogramOrnithischia.jpg it will at least give you a list of names you can check individually for the time. It is not perfect but it is among the most complete. This site will help in checking them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dinosaur_genera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cladogram from ["The phylogeny of the ornithischian dinosaurs"](http://www.dinochecker.com/papers/phylogeny-of-the-ornithischian-dinosaurs_Butler_et_al_2008.pdf), Butler, Upchurch, & Norman, *Journal of Systematic Palaeontology* (2008):

[image]

Of these, :

- [Ferganocephale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferganocephale) (*Pachycephalosauridae*)
- [Chaoyangsaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaoyangsaurus)
- [Camptosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camptosaurus) (*Ankylopollexia*)
- [Uteodon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uteodon) (*Ankylopollexia*)
- [Callovosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callovosaurus) (*Dryosauridae*)
- [Dryosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryosaurus) (*Dryosauridae*)
- [Dysalotosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysalotosaurus) (*Dryosauridae*)

lived during the Jurassic.

---

The synopsis explains well why this classification is subject to adjustment, and why you may have seen contradictory models in your research:

> **SYNOPSIS** Ornithischia is a familiar and diverse clade of dinosaurs whose global phylogeny has
>   remained largely unaltered since early cladistic analyses in the mid 1980s. Current understanding of
>   ornithischian evolution is hampered by a paucity of explicitly numerical phylogenetic analyses that
>   consider the entire clade. As a result, it is difficult to assess the robustness of current phylogenetic
>   hypotheses for Ornithischia and the effect that the addition of new taxa or characters is likely to have
>   on the overall topology of the clade.
>
> The new phylogenetic analysis presented here incorporates a range of new basal taxa and characters
>   in an attempt to rigorously test global ornithischian phylogeny. Parsimony analysis is carried out
>   with 46 taxa and 221 characters. Although the strict component consensus tree shows poor resolution
>   in a number of areas, application of reduced consensus methods provides a well-resolved picture
>   of ornithischian interrelationships. Surprisingly, Heterodontosauridae is placed as the most basal
>   group of all well-known ornithischians, phylogenetically distant from a stem-defined Ornithopoda,
>   creating a topology that is more congruent with the known ornithischian stratigraphical record. There
>   is no evidence for a monophyletic ‘Fabrosauridae’, and Lesothosaurus (the best-known ‘fabrosaur’)
>   occupies an unusual position as the most basal member of Thyreophora. Other relationships within
>   Thyreophora remain largely stable. The primitive thyreophoran Scelidosaurus is the sister taxon of
>   Eurypoda (stegosaurs and ankylosaurs), rather than a basal ankylosaur as implied by some previous
>   studies.
>
> The taxonomic content of Ornithopoda differs significantly from previous analyses and basal
>   relationships within the clade are weakly supported, requiring further investigation. ‘Hypsilophodontidae’
>   is paraphyletic, with some taxa (Agilisaurus, Hexinlusaurus, Othnielia) placed outside
>   of Ornithopoda as non-cerapodans. Ceratopsia and Pachycephalosauria are monophyletic and are
>   united as Marginocephalia; however, the stability of these clades is reduced by a number of poorly
>   preserved basal taxa.
>
> This analysis reaffirms much of the currently accepted ornithischian topology. Nevertheless, instability
>   in the position and content of several clades (notably Heterodontosauridae and Ornithopoda)
>   indicates that considerable future work on ornithischian phylogeny is required and causes problems
>   for several current phylogenetic definitions.